# How do I protect a nested route, that is nested in a protected route, with react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, react-router-dom

I protect `/dashboard/*` routes with a `RequireAuth` outlet component. `RequireAuth` verifies a jwt token, and this works as expected. Navigating either with the url bar, or a react-router-dom  component, from an unprotected route to a protected route verifies the token before granting access.

However, once I have landed on a 'dashboard/*' component I am able to navigate within those nested components using a  without re-verifying the token (if the url is typed directly in then the token *is* verified.

How can I alter the behavior so that:

1.) user navigates from /login to /dashboard

2.) token is verified

3.) user navigates from /dashboard to /dashboard/new-path

4.) token is verified

**App.jsx** routes

```
      <Routes>
        {/* protected routes */}
        <Route element={<RequireAuth />}>
          <Route path="dashboard/*" element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Route>

        {/* public routes */}
        <Route index element={<Public />} />
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
      </Routes>
```

**Dashboard.jsx** routes

```
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<DashboardTimeline />} />
        <Route path="/my-paths" element={<MyPaths />} />
        <Route path="/new-path" element={<NewPathWizard />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
```

**RequireAuth.jsx**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation, Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { selectCurrentToken, logOut } from './authSlice';
import { useVerifyTokenMutation } from './authApiSlice';
import FullScreenLoading from '../../components/general/FullScreenLoading';

function RequireAuth() {
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const location = useLocation();
  const [verifyToken] = useVerifyTokenMutation();
  const token = useSelector(selectCurrentToken);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const authenticateToken = async () => {
      const response = await verifyToken({ token }).unwrap();
      const { verified } = response.data;
      setIsLoading(false);
      setAuthenticated(verified);
    };

    if (token) {
      authenticateToken()
        .catch((error) => {
          const { verified } = error.data;
          dispatch(logOut());
          setIsLoading(false);
          setAuthenticated(verified);
        });
    } else {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setAuthenticated(false);
    }
  }, []);

  if (isLoading === true) {
    return <FullScreenLoading />;
  }

  return (
    authenticated && !isLoading
      ? <Outlet />
      : <Navigate to="/" state={{ from: location }} replace />
  );
}
export default RequireAuth;
```

I have tried wrapping the nested routes within `Dashboard.jsx` in the `RequireAuth` component as well, but it made no difference.

Comment: Can you [edit] to share all the relevant code you are working with, especially this `RequireAuth` component that does the auth/token check? See [mcve].

Comment: So basically you want `authenticateToken` and `verifyToken` called for each navigation to a protected route? Even after the user is already been authenticated?

Comment: @DrewReese, correct, I'd like to check the token on each navigation. Admittedly, though, I do not know if this a best practice and the seemingly default behavior of react router has given me some pause.

Comment: Sure, I think I understand. Can you clarify what you mean with "and the seemingly default behavior of react router has given me some pause"?

Comment: I'm interpreting the behavior I'm seeing (the RequieAuth only firing on the initial nav into the protected routes) as perhaps indication that it's expected to "protect" entry into the routes, but once authorization is granted it's assumed the user can navigate within the protected route space (and not re-render the RequireAuth component, unless they leave the protected space and re-enter). Just an assumption though. @DrewReese

Comment: I see. Yeah, React-Router-Dom is opinionated on a lot of things, but the what/where/when/how of checking authentication status isn't one of them. You are basically free to implement what you need. The layout route component rendering an `Outlet` is about as deep as RRD gets into it as a recommended pattern.

Comment: I see, yeah it makes more sense that what I'm seeing isn't 'default' behavior with the auth intention like I was thinking. Thanks for the answer, that's a great solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the user's authentication/token status checked for each navigation then you can add the current location's `pathname` as a dependency for the `useEffect` hook. When the `location.pathname` changes, the effect will be run.

Example;

```
function RequireAuth() {
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const location = useLocation();
  const { pathname } = location; // <-- access current pathname

  const [verifyToken] = useVerifyTokenMutation();
  const token = useSelector(selectCurrentToken);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const authenticateToken = async () => {
      setIsLoading(false); // <-- start/restart loading condition
      try {
        const response = await verifyToken({ token }).unwrap();
        const { verified } = response.data;
        setAuthenticated(verified);
      } catch(error) {
        const { verified } = error.data;
        dispatch(logOut());
        setAuthenticated(verified);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false); // <-- clear loading when finished
      }
    };

    if (token) {
      authenticateToken();
    } else {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setAuthenticated(false);
    }
  }, [pathname]); // <-- add as dependency

  if (isLoading) {
    return <FullScreenLoading />;
  }

  return (
    authenticated && !isLoading
      ? <Outlet />
      : <Navigate to="/" state={{ from: location }} replace />
  );
}

export default RequireAuth;
```

Comment: Does it actially stop and wait for the RequireAuth to be finished before starting rendering children? From my testing it seems that children useEffect will be called at the same time still

Comment: @Ren Does *what* actually stop and wait for `RequireAuth`? `RequireAuth` is a React component so it simply renders its sub-ReactTree as part of being rendered as part of its parent component's sub-ReactTree.

Comment: For some reason I expected that RequireAuth will trigger other components to be on hold with loading data in useEffect. That is if there are child components under RequireAuth route and they have some async code to load data from useEffect with `[]` that will be still triggered even though RequireAuth has not finished the check yet. In some conditions I observe that such fetch of data can even fail faster than RequireAuth has finished checking the user token

Comment: @Ren If `isLoading` is true in the above example then the `FullScreenLoading` component is rendered, otherwise either the `Outlet` or `Navigate` component is conditionally rendered.